# OSM, OSMSharp, OSMdroid, MapBox?! which one to use?

Tags: cordova, xamarin, openstreetmap, osmdroid, mapbox

We are in process of beginning a new project that needs to render **offline maps** of certain areas.

Showing pre-computed (from a web-server source) **routes** are needed as well ( no need to in-app route computing)

We are targeting **android** devices but we must be very cautious for future cross-platform compatibilities, that would be releasing the same application (with minimum changes in both of UI and Logic of the application), for other platforms (iOS, Windows, Windows Phone).

I considered using of **PhoneGap**, but by using PhoneGap, the only thing that is shared is UI.
then I thought of using **Xamarin**, Xamarin is more like it, but the "**OSMSharp**" library has very very poor documentations. I fear using **OSMSharp** and being unable to solve problems that may occur during app development.

And about **mapbox**, how is it? does it satisfy our needs?

I'd like to benefit anyone's ideas who know something about these stuff.

Comment: I've only got experience with skobbler SDKs (http://developer.skobbler.com) - that only supports iOS & Android but it does support offline maps quite well (on request download or prebundling with the app).

Comment: maybe this question would get better answers (or would be better suited) on https://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: Thanks for your attention "Ando" , I'm checking this SDK if it meets our requirements. I'll ask my question in openstreetmap too.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32999/osmsharp-osmdroid-mapbox-skobbler-which-one-to-use

Comment: Please don't do crossposts as they consume a lot of time of people that like to help you and make it hard for a reader to find final answers when looking for a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a free opensource solution, some feedback about Android-only solutions:

- offline maps of certain areas + off-line routing => Mapsforge+Graphhopper.
- offline maps + online routing => osmdroid + OSMBonusPack
  You can also store precomputed routes, as GeoJSON or KML local files for instance.
- PhoneGap: I don't think you can easily have offline maps, as it is an HTML-wrapping solution.
- MapBox: the Android SDK is a fork from osmdroid. It is not stable yet, there is no routing included. I don't see any added value currently, compared with osmdroid.

As a conclusion: in your context, the choice between Mapsforge and osmdroid could be difficult to do. 
osmdroid is robust, but offline files can be huge. 
Mapsforge file format is much smaller, but the map refresh seems quite slow (Galaxy Ace 2).

(I didn't know Skobbler. This is interesting. Thanks Ando)

Answer (score 0):

Well to start off, I would recommend using `OSMdroid` which is absolutely good with offline maps and optimization and owners help you a lot with any questions. If you are looking for cross platform, I'm not sure this is the API you are looking for, but for Android certainly this is the most widely and easiest API to adapt and build on.

Have a look at `OSMdroid`:https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be crossplatform i would think about NOT using the osmdroid/sharpdroid/???-api directly to set the display content of the map but work with kml file format.

For osmdroid there is a kml-viewer support in the [OSMBonusPack](http://osmbonuspack.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/). i donot know if there is any kml-support for ios or OSMSharp